# How to give reference of Nuget package in Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, jenkins, nuget

I have a vb.net project and that is uploaded to **GIT**. For the lib like **Oracle.Data.Access.dll** i have created the **Nuget** package and that is stored on the another server.

Now I need to build the code, So I took the code from **GIT** and download the **Nuget** package from server and install it. Everything works fine.

But if build my code from **jenkins** it is failing.

What steps should i need to follow? Or I need to give **Nuget** reference from my project?

Please suggest.

Comment: Without seeing the job config it is hard to tell. Do you have a step in your Jenkins job to download the file?

Comment: >"So I took the code from GIT and download the Nuget package from server and install it." What did you do exactly because once added to the project, there is no such things to do except a "nuget restore" (that should also be done on the server one way or another...)

Comment: I don't have any step in my Jenkins job for nuget as of now.

Comment: @Philippe On local computer if you want to build the code, then you can took the code from GIT and down load the nuget package and install it. Everything works fine.

Comment: But when I try to build the code from jenkins, it is giving errors.

Comment: Which error? What are you doing? How? Give more information. I seem to perceive that you do things quite wrong but you give so few information that it's like your asking to blind man to solve a puzzle!

Comment: Error is the "an attempt was made to load an assembly with an incorrect format : path\oracle.dataaccess.dll"

Comment: My question is how do we give the reference for nuget package in the solution, please share any document or any link you have.

Comment: @Pirate, Have you restore the nuget package when you build with jenkins?

Comment: Yes I restore the package before build.

Answer (score 1):

> What steps should i need to follow?

You should restore the NuGet packages before attempting to build the source:

Some Steps:

1. Navigate to the “project” page.
2. Select “Configure”.
3. Find the “Add build step”.
4. Click “Add build step”.

[image]

5. Select “Execute Windows batch command”.
6. Re-arrange the build order by dragging the new build step to the top.

[image]

7. In the Command field insert: \nuget.exe restore "\Yousolution.sln"
8. Save.

Note:The step should be moved above the MSBuild step because in order the build to be successful you are going to need all package downloaded beforehand.

For some more details, please refer to [Integrate Jenkins with MSBuild and NuGet](https://automatetheplanet.com/integrate-jenkins-msbuild-nuget/).

Comment: I have two nuget packages. How would jenkins know which nuget should be restore. I need to restore both the package but It is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkin needs to be told to pull the Packages\ folder out of source control.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to do that?